# How to style all the same XSL FO elements? XSL FO like CSS?

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Is a way in XSL FO how to style all the same XSL FO elements in once? Source is in XML.

EXAMPLE:

```
<fo:table-row> {border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0; }
```

INSTEAD OF:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="border">
    <xsl:attribute name="border-bottom">1px solid #f0f0f0</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Its a big mess always using `xsl:use-attribute-sets` at all places with `<fo:table-row>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you are creating XSL FO from XML and XSL and that would not apply because you would do something in an template-match for whatever creates your table-row. So you would only be writing it once.

Now, you could use the same concept and create an identity XSL that modifies your XSL FO input to a new XSL FO and uses `<xsl:template match="fo:table-row">` and applies all your rules.